# How can I measure 400 kHz frequency?

Tags: microcontroller, frequency, measurement, counter

I would like to measure a 400 kHz sine wave.

I am thinking of converting the 400 kHz sine wave to a square wave using a Schmitt trigger and then measuring the signal with a microcontroller. Yes, the frequency changes after each power up. Therefore, once powered, the frequency doesn't change unless the power is turned off and turned on again.
I would like to measure the frequency after 0.5second, and at max, 1 second.
It would be nice to have an accuracy of within 200Hz.

I don't think using a microcontroller to measure 400 kHz is a good idea due to its sampling rate.

Can anyone please help me out?
Does anyone know what these are, and if they can help?

[IC DIVIDER DIV X2 ECL 3.3V 8SOIC](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/onsemi/MC100LVEL32DG/920728)

[IC COUNTER 14STAGE BIN 16-TSSOP](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/onsemi/MC74HC4060ADTR2G/2120916)

Comment: How accurate do you need the measurement to be? Is the frequency changing or is it constant? How long are you willing to wait to get an accurate measurement?

Comment: 400kHz is not particularly high... sample rate doesn't matter, use counters instead. Example: https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/td_libs_FreqMeasure.html FYI, you can't mix 100k ECL and 74HC families anyway, use just one kind.

Comment: Some more context is required. Presumably this 400kHz can vary (? else, why measure it ? ) What is the measurement result to be used for ? ...

Comment: What do you want to measure from the sine wave and how accurately? Frequency? Amplitude? The amplitude needs to be large enough for a Schmitt trigger input, so what amplitude the sine wave has?

Comment: Even a cheap simple PIC can measure frequency at tens of MHz using the on-chip peripherals. 400kHz is easy if you use the hardware most MCUs have.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany can u please direct me an example of a counter that is used to measure frequency.

Comment: Your comparator/Schmitt trigger -> MCU should be fine, but the devil’s in the details. What amplitude of the signal? AC coupled? DC offset?

Comment: @SamShurp See my earlier comment

Comment: Google PIC frequency meter for teh codez.

Answer (score 4):

Feed your 400 kHz square signal to a (any) counter IC to reduce the frequency of the signal (the counter acts as a frequency divider, but with higher division rates than your divide-by-2). Then use an interrupt on your MCU to increase a counter variable and a timer to calculate the period.

Most datasheets for counter ICs should give you a clear picture of how it should work.

As @Unimportant noted: Most microcontrollers have built-in counters, use those if you can.

Comment: Many microcontrollers allow IO pins to be configured as source for timers/counters with configurable pre-scalers. So an external counter is seldom required.

Comment: Would you please show me an example of how to use a counter. Can u recommend me one. I hope to hear your opinion. Is there a specific name for frequency measured counter?